# SQL: efficiently classifying multiple fields of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a data table called 'visits' that contains four columns: a patient ID, and three coded medical diagnoses. Each row represents a visit to a physician. Something like

```
PATIENTID  DIAGNOSIS1  DIAGNOSIS2  DIAGNOSIS3
0001             0234        0020          NA
0002             9383          NA          NA
0003             5983        8372        7747
0004             1143          NA          NA
```

I also have a table 'class' that classifies diseases into three categories:

```
DIAGNOSIS  CLASS
     0234      1
     0020      3
     9383      2
     5983      2
     8372      1
     7747      1
     1143      3
```

I would like to end up with a table that gives the classification of each diagnosis; something like

```
PATIENTID  DIAGNOSIS1  DIAGNOSIS2  DIAGNOSIS3  CLASS1  CLASS2  CLASS3
0001             0234        0020          NA       1       3      NA
0002             9383          NA          NA       2      NA      NA
0003             5983        8372        7747       2       1       1
0004             1143          NA          NA       3      NA      NA
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? My first guess is to repeatedly left-join 'visits' and 'class' as follows:

```
SELECT
    v3.DIAGNOSIS1,
    v3.DIAGNOSIS2,
    v3.DIAGNOSIS3,
    v3.CLASS1,
    v3.CLASS2,
    c3.CLASS AS CLASS3
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        v2.DIAGNOSIS1,
        v2.DIAGNOSIS2, 
        v2.DIAGNOSIS3,
        v2.CLASS1
        c2.CLASS AS CLASS2
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            v1.DIAGNOSIS1,
            v1.DIAGNOSIS2,
            v1.DIAGNOSIS3,
            c1.CLASS AS CLASS1
        FROM visit AS v1
        LEFT JOIN class AS c1
        ON (v1.DIAGNOSIS1=c1.DIAGNOSIS)
        )
    AS v2 
    LEFT JOIN class AS c2
    ON (v2.DIAGNOSIS2=c2.DIAGNOSIS)
    )
AS v3 
LEFT JOIN class AS c3
ON (v3.DIAGNOSIS3=c3.DIAGNOSIS)
```

But this is messy (especially as the number of 'diagnosis' columns grows), and probably quite slow. Is there a better way?

Comment: pivotting with `GROUP BY`  and using `MAX(CASE END)` is generally a better idea, but i assume you need to have it dynamic also?

Comment: *"But this is messy (especially as the number of 'diagnosis' columns grows), and probably quite slow. Is there a better way? "* The whole table structure is a mess not only the query.. You ideally should normalize the visits table as you limit the patients max diagnosis/visits right now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the table `class` 3 times to `visit`, once for each of the columns `diagnosis1`, `diagnosis2` and `diagnosis3`:

```
select
  v.*,
  c1.class class1,
  c2.class class2,
  c3.class class3
from visit v 
left join class c1 on c1.diagnosis = v.diagnosis1
left join class c2 on c2.diagnosis = v.diagnosis2
left join class c3 on c3.diagnosis = v.diagnosis3
```